# Create database schema with terraform

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I created RDS instance using `aws_db_instance` (`main.tf`):

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
    identifier           = "${module.config.database["db_inst_name"]}"
    allocated_storage    = 20
    storage_type         = "gp2"
    engine               = "mysql"
    engine_version       = "5.7"
    instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
    name                 = "${module.config.database["db_name_prefix"]}${terraform.workspace}"
    username             = "${module.config.database["db_username"]}"
    password             = "${module.config.database["db_password"]}"
    parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
    skip_final_snapshot  = true
}
```

Can I also create database schemas from file `schema.sql` with `terraform apply`?

```
$ tree -L 1                                                                                               
.
├── main.tf
└── schema.sql
```

Comment: Databases tend to be long-lived and require modifications to their schemas over time, so I'd caution against using Terraform to manage the schema unless you're confident it will change rarely or never. When changing database schema we tend to need to be explicit about _how_ to migrate (in order to avoid data loss). That's not a good fit for Terraform's declarative approach, where we tell Terraform the result we want and let Terraform figure out how to make it happen. There are specialized tools tailored to this problem which I'd suggest using after letting Terraform create the empty database.

Comment: Project is in very early designing phase. I need that to setup basic environment with dummy data to provide some foundations for the app to work with ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a provisioner (https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) for that:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  identifier           = module.config.database["db_inst_name"]
  allocated_storage    = 20
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  name                 = "${module.config.database["db_name_prefix"]}${terraform.workspace}"
  username             = module.config.database["db_username"]
  password             = module.config.database["db_password"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mysql --host=${self.address} --port=${self.port} --user=${self.username} --password=${self.password} < ./schema.sql"
    }
  }

#Apply scheme by using bastion host
resource "aws_db_instance" "default_bastion" {
  identifier           = module.config.database["db_inst_name"]
  allocated_storage    = 20
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  name                 = "${module.config.database["db_name_prefix"]}${terraform.workspace}"
  username             = module.config.database["db_username"]
  password             = module.config.database["db_password"]
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true

  provisioner "file" {
      connection {
      user        = "ec2-user"
      host        = "bastion.example.com"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/ec2_cert.pem")
    }

    source      = "./schema.sql"
    destination = "~"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      user        = "ec2-user"
      host        = "bastion.example.com"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/ec2_cert.pem")
    }

    command = "mysql --host=${self.address} --port=${self.port} --user=${self.username} --password=${self.password} < ~/schema.sql"
  }
}
```

mysql client needs to be installed on your device.

If you don't have direct access to your DB, there is also a `remote-exec` provisioner, where you can use a bastion host (transfer file to remote place with `file` provisioner first).

If your schema is not to complex, you could also use the MySQL provider of terraform:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html

Comment: @DJAIPee can you show how would you do it via a bastion host?

Comment: @Shell_Leko I updated my config. It is not tested, but should give you a rough idea, how it's supposed to work.